# C compiler cannot create executables during build of Coreutils with LLVM

Tags: ubuntu, clang, llvm, klee

I am looking for some assistance in figuring out the solution to an error that pops up during the configure command of Coreutils with llvm.

I use the command:

`CC=wllvm ../configure --disable-nls CFLAGS="-g -O1 -Xclang -disable-llvm-passes -D__NO_STRING_INLINES  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -U__OPTIMIZE__"`

and receive the errors:

```
checking whether the compiler works...no
configure: error: in '/home/abhinath/coreutils/obj-llvm
configure: error: c compiler cannot create executables
```

I have run the command `export LLVM_COMPILER=clang` beforehand

I have installed and set up **clang-6.0** and **clang++-6.0** on my Ubuntu OS using the commands

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-6.0 1000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-6.0 1000
sudo update-alternatives --config clang
sudo update-alternatives --config clang++
```

The config.log file with errors generated can be viewed here, which also shows 
`wllvm: command not found`:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ExbLhT2tWRyGSAb67mAgu6D9y3AknZ2v

Comment: `CC=wllvm` - what is `wllvm`? llvm's C compiler is called `clang`.

Comment: @Mat wllvm is a C compiler, part of whole-program-llvm (WLLVM). I'm following the instructions from the tutorials on klee's github. Specifically step 3 from here https://klee.github.io/tutorials/testing-coreutils/

Comment: Ok. Look at your log file and see what it has to say about `wllvm`

Comment: @Mat I've taken a look at the logs and it says wllvm: command not found ,as you can see too. Not sure how to address this

Comment: Have you searched your system for the program `wllvm`? Where is it installed?

Comment: If you did `pip install wllvm` as a non-root user, it probably installed the executables somewhere that isn't on your PATH.  You'll probably have to find that directory and add it.  You should probably make sure you can compile and run "hello world" with `wllvm` before trying to go on.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude its installed using pip install --upgrade wllvm . so its on the location /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah I see. I used the command `sudo -H python -m pip install wllvm` and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, nothing in `/usr/local` is included in the system directories.

And a non-standard location like `usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/some-directory` even less so.

You need to find the *exact* location (as in full and absolute path) of the `wllvm` program and either use that full path or add its directory to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: `sudo -H python -m pip install wllvm` seemed to the trick and it works now.